# read json in Ruby and set variables for use in another class

Tags: ruby, json

The need here is to read a json file and to make the variables which is done from one class and use them with in another class.  What I have so far is

helper.rb

```
class MAGEINSTALLER_Helper
    #note nonrelated items removed
    require 'fileutils'
    #REFACTOR THIS LATER
    def load_settings()
        require 'json'
        file = File.open("scripts/installer_settings.json", "rb")
        contents = file.read
        file.close
        #note this should be changed for a better content check.. ie:valid json
        #so it's a hack for now
        if contents.length > 5 

            begin
                parsed = JSON.parse(contents)
            rescue SystemCallError
                puts "must redo the settings file"
            else    
                puts parsed['bs_mode']
                parsed.each do |key, value|
                    puts "#{key}=>#{value}"
                    instance_variable_set("@" + key, value) #better way?
                end
            end
        else
            puts "must redo the settings file"
        end
    end

    #a method to provide feedback simply 
    def download(from,to)
        puts "completed download for #{from}\n"
    end
end
```

Which is called in a file of  Pre_start.rb

```
class Pre_start
    #note nonrelated items removed
    def initialize(params=nil)
        puts 'World'

        mi_h = MAGEINSTALLER_Helper.new

        mi_h.load_settings()
        bs_MAGEversion=instance_variable_get("@bs_MAGEversion") #doesn't seem to work
        file="www/depo/newfile-#{bs_MAGEversion}.tar.gz"
        if !File.exist?(file)
            mi_h.download("http://www.dom.com/#{bs_MAGEversion}/file-#{bs_MAGEversion}.tar.gz",file)
        else
            puts "mage package exists"
        end

    end
end
```

the josn file is valid json and is a simple object (note there is more just showing the relevant)

```
{
    "bs_mode":"lite",
    "bs_MAGEversion":"1.8.0.0"
}
```

The reason I need to have a json settings file is that I will need to pull settings from a bash script and later a php script.  This file is the common thread that is used to pass settings each share and need to match.

Right now I end up with an empty string for the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `instance_variable_set`is creating the variable inside `MAGEINSTALLER_Helper` class. That's the reason why you can't access these variables.

You can refactor it into a module, like this:

```
require 'fileutils'
require 'json'

module MAGEINSTALLER_Helper
  #note nonrelated items removed
  #REFACTOR THIS LATER
  def load_settings()

    content = begin 
      JSON.load_file('scripts/installer_settings.json')
    rescue
      puts 'must redo the settings file'
      {} # return an empty Hash object
    end

    parsed.each {|key, value| instance_variable_set("@#{key}", value)}
  end

  #a method to provide feedback simply 
  def download(from,to)
    puts "completed download for #{from}\n"
  end
end

class PreStart
  include MAGEINSTALLER_Helper
  #note nonrelated items removed
  def initialize(params=nil)
    puts 'World'

    load_settings # The method is available inside the class
    file="www/depo/newfile-#{@bs_MAGEversion}.tar.gz"
    if !File.exist?(file)
      download("http://www.dom.com/#{@bs_MAGEversion}/file-#{@bs_MAGEversion}.tar.gz",file)
    else
      puts "mage package exists"
    end
  end
end
```

I refactored a little bit to more Rubish style.

Comment: This was the ticket, and I like where it is going.  so this is more ruby style then?  tk

Answer (score 0):

We do something similar to this all the time in code at work. The problem, and solution, is proper use of variables and scoping in the main level of your code. We use YAML, you're using JSON, but the idea is the same.

Typically we define a constant, like `CONFIG`, which we load the YAML into, in our main code, and which is then available in all the code we require. For you, using JSON instead:

```
require 'json'

require_relative 'helper'

CONFIG = JSON.load_file('path/to/json')
```

At this point `CONFIG` would be available to the top-level code and in "helper.rb" code.

As an alternate way of doing it, just load your JSON in either file. The load-time is negligible and it'll still be the same data.

Since the JSON data should be static for the run-time of the program, it's OK to use it in a CONSTANT. Storing it in an instance variable only makes sense if the data would vary from instance to instance of the code, which makes no sense when you're loading data from a JSON or YAML-type file.

Also, notice that I'm using a method from the JSON class. Don't go through the rigamarole you're using to try to copy the JSON into the instance variable.

Stripping your code down as an example:

```
require 'fileutils'
require 'json'

CONTENTS = JSON.load_file('scripts/installer_settings.json')

class MAGEINSTALLER_Helper

  def download(from,to)

    puts "completed download for #{from}\n"

  end
end
```

---

```
class Pre_start

  def initialize(params=nil)

    file = "www/depo/newfile-#{ CONFIG['bs_MAGEversion'] }.tar.gz"
    if !File.exist?(file)
      mi_h.download("http://www.dom.com/#{ CONFIG['bs_MAGEversion'] }/file-#{ CONFIG['bs_MAGEversion'] }.tar.gz", file)
    else
      puts "mage package exists"
    end

  end
end
```

`CONFIG` can be initialized/loaded in either file, just do it from the top-level before you need to access the contents.

Remember, Ruby starts executing it at the top of the first file and reads downward. Code that is outside of `def`, `class` and `module` blocks gets executed as it's encountered, so the `CONFIG` initialization will happen as soon as Ruby sees that code. If that happens before you start calling your methods and creating instances of classes then your code will be happy.

Comment: I think I follow here, but it's still a little muddy.  You are saying that at the very top entire file to put `CONFIG` so when I load it through the helper then it'll be available to all the classes?  New to ruby so still getting my barings atm

Answer (score 0):

On this line:

```
    bs_MAGEversion=instance_variable_get("@bs_MAGEversion") #doesn't seem to work
```

instance_variable_get isn't retrieving from the mi_h Object, which is where your value is stored.  The way you've used it, that line is equivalent to:

```
    bs_MAGEversion=@bs_MAGEversion
```

Changing it to mi_h.instance_variable_get would work.  It would also be painfully ugly ruby.  But I sense that's not quite what you're after.  If I read you correctly, you want this line:

```
    mi_h.load_settings()
```

to populate @bs_MAGEversion and @bs_mode in your Pre_start object.  Ruby doesn't quite work that way.  The closest thing to what you're looking for here would probably be a mixin, as described here:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_modules.html